# RestSharp return OutputRows (HTML)

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, restsharp

I'm doing a ETL Process, extracting from a API, but I don't know how I do to output the rows;
That's my code, but I don't know how to do a "FOREACH" to return.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/action/api/getCursos");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "KONVIVA xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Can you add a sample response? Also, I try to use System.Net.WebClient()

Comment: The trick is getting the response into a class object and from there you can do your foreach

Comment: If the response is basic Json then use Json2csharp.com to build your classes and use System.Web.Script.Serialization; JavaScriptSerializer. If it is more complicated Json then use QuickType and NewtonSoft.Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i create a "input and output" variable (TESTE) and split JSON in "}" in a foreach and another foreach splited in ",".

```
    foreach (var i in response.Content.Split('}'))
    {
        foreach (var j in i.Split(','))
        {
            OutputAPIBuffer.AddRow();
            OutputAPIBuffer.Teste = j;

        }
    }
```